# How to show if $A (A△B)△C=A△(B△C)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

I'm working on problem that asks me to show that for any set $a$,$b$,$c$ $(A△B)△C=A△(B△C)$

In my opinion, I can just use associative law of set theory and just conclude that left equals the right. But then this question is too simple and I assume there is other way to prove that left equals right?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Try proving that any element $x$ of the left hand side must be an element of the right hand side, and vice versa.

You can't use associativity; you're being asked to prove this associativity property.

Comment: ok so what i did was simplify left side: 1.[x l x∈A v x ∈B)^¬(x∈A^x∈B)] v [x∈C ^ ¬(x∈c)] 2. A ∪ B ∩ not(A ∩ B) ∪ C ∩ not(C) am i on the right track??